# download implementation to jar files and use it as offline library in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-mlkit

I wanna export the implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-mlvision:15.0.0' and implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2' to firebase-mlvision:15.0.0.jar and firebase-core:15.0.2.jar files

Example:
[image]

Because I want to make a module for my unity project using firebase with my android studio jar files and I know that I need to use offline jar library files

anyone know how to do it? if I need to download them, can you give me a link?

Comment: Gradle stores the jars in a cache. Once you download it, you don't need to re-download that specific version again, unless you delete or move the cache

Comment: i know but when i exported to jar files in myproject\app\build\intermediates\packaged-classes\debug\classes.jar and copy to my unity asset file it can't access to firebase api and when i use implementation it seems that the classes.jar file has a really low size so firebase api aren't included in that jar, or can you tell me how to export all the jar files into a single jar?